# how can i cache couchbase documents in java?

Tags: java, couchbase

i have to cache all the documents which are returned when i execute the below query

```
select * from `contact` where type="org"
```

What will be the best approach to do this?

Comment: Where do you need to cache it? in the database or in the server? How many documents are returned?

Comment: i need to cache it on the server side. it return around 500 documents

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how you want to access the cached documents. Without knowing more details, it's hard to say what's best. The _simplest_ approach would be to stick them in a Map where the key is the document ID.

Comment: i have organization document in the form http://myjson.com/1cgfy6 where organizationKey is the document id. i will be accessing the organization documents to retrieve all the organization roles whose any addressasoc  contains addressid which is present in another document of type "address" and is of this format http://myjson.com/jehmm

Answer (score 1):

Use spring cache and add @EnableCaching on your application configuration class, and declare a method that will return CacheManager bean,

```
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

private static final String cacheName ="YourCacheMap";
private static final String cacheManager ="AppCacheManager";

@Bean(name = "AppCacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager(){
    final SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    final List<AbstractValueAdaptingCache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
    final ConcurrentMapCache cacheMap = new ConcurrentMapCache("YourCacheMap",
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(100).build().asMap(), false);
    caches.add(cacheMap);
    cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

And in your repository service class use @Cacheable annotation on method that you want to cache

```
@Cacheable(value = cacheName, cacheManager = cacheManager, key = "#p0"
        ,unless = "#result == null || #p0==null")
public List<YourDataType> getResult(String type) {
    // here you will return your results
    return new ArrayList<YourDataType>();
}
```

Comment: i dont have spring in my current project. Is there any other solution that i can try. we are already using ehcache framework in our project. Is there any way that can be used ?